# OpenAPI / Swagger-ui: Auto-generated JSON in form ignores parameter name

Tags: swagger, servicestack, swagger-ui, openapi

*EDIT: Found [this post](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/swagger-put-post-body-value-issue/4790) after posting here, se answer below*

I am using ServiceStack and its OpenApi plugin. I am not sure though if this is an Swagger-ui problem, ServiceStack or something in my code.

I have a POST endpoint where I expect the Customer property to be populated:

```
[Route("/api/customers/", "POST", Summary = "Creates a new customer")]
public class CreateCustomer : IReturn<CreateCustomerResponse>
{
    [ApiMember(Description = "The customer data", ParameterType = "body", IsRequired = true)]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

The Customer class has a number of properties, like "Firstname" etc.

When I review this in the swagger-ui, I can see that the "Example value" lacks the name "Customer" that the JSON object "Customer" should be placed within:

[image]

If I then press "Try it out"-button, I can see that Swagger-ui sends the "Customer" object directly without specifying that it should be inside the "Customer" (I removed the backslashes and cut out properties from the Customer json for clarity):

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{  
   "PopulationRegistryNumber": "string",  
   "Firstname": "string",  
   "MiddleName": "string",  
   "Lastname": "string"
 }
```

What I was expected was:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '
{ "Customer": 
   {
       "PopulationRegistryNumber": "string",
       "Firstname": "string",
       "MiddleName": "string",
       "Lastname": "string"
   }
}
```

Now, if I remove the ServiceStack `ApiMember` attribute, then the Swagger-ui has the correct JSON, but it adds a separate field in the form for "Customer", that is misleading and should not be there, since it should be part of the body.

[image]

Is this "Customer" field a swagger issue, a ServiceStack thing or something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is a thread on ServiceStack forum](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/swagger-put-post-body-value-issue/4790/17), where this exact issue is discussed.

The last post by xplicit comes with a solution, even though its not clear to me how exactly the attributes work together.

The solution, which *partly* resolves my issue, is:

> You can use [ApiMember(ExcludeInSchema=true)] and
> [ApiMember(ParameterType=“model”)] to exclude properties you don’t
> want to see in Open API definitions. For example
>
> ```
> [Route("/workflow/{ProjectId}", "POST")]
> [Api(BodyParameter = GenerateBodyParameter.Always, IsRequired = true)]
> public class WorkflowPostRequest : IReturn<Workflow>
> {
>     [ApiMember(ParameterType = "path", ExcludeInSchema = true)]
>     public string ProjectId { get; set; }
>
>     [ApiMember(ParameterType = "model")]
>     public Workflow Workflow { get; set; }
> }
> ```
>
> will generate this Open API definition:
>
> [image]

The forum post is [here](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/swagger-put-post-body-value-issue/4790/17).

*NOTE:*

The attribute on the class, `[Api(BodyParameter = GenerateBodyParameter.Always, IsRequired = true)]`, is not needed in my case, the correct JSON and look in swagger works anyways.

So, basically, all you need to do it seems, is to change from `ParameterType = "body"` to `ParameterType = "model"`

Also note that variables that are in path, query etc, must manually be excluded using `ExcludeInSchema`, which is annoying but doable.